# I made a mistake on a book that is now almost done printing...What should I do?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, pdf, client-relations, academic-publishing

I was working on this research book and I sent them a copy of the books (2 different versions/language) probably 4-6 times. Everything was great in the first few PDF I sent them, and then they asked me to combine the two files into one. Now I was working with Indesign so when I combined these two files some things needed to be changed. After I sent them the final PDF they sent it to the printer immediately since they proofread the files before. Not until a couple of days later did I checked the file again and noticed that one of the images shifted and covered the credit for the source of that image. I'm pretty sure they haven't noticed it yet but what should I do once they find out? Are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 7):

The only solutions are...

## Call **immediately**, RIGHT NOW, to see if you can stop the process. You may be able to.

Don't email.. CALL so it's immediate. Call the printer if you can. If not call the client.

If you can't catch it in time... options are...

- Pay for a reprint
- Live with the error

That's all you can do. If a reprint is warranted, the print provider will *not* do it for free. So someone will have to pay for it. The bright side *might* be if only one or two pages have errors, they may be able to only reprint a part of the book, especially if you can stop the process *before* it gets to the bindery stage.

---

Sidebar, if you provided files to the client, then it's *their* responsibility to verify things are correct before passing files onto production.

See here: [Who is responsible for text mistakes in a print project?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53386/who-is-responsible-for-text-mistakes-in-a-print-project)

Comment: If you manage to stop it before binding, you might need to reprint _the whole signature_, which will increase the cost even more if the book is offset-printed.

Comment: Thanks you! I will try to call them and see what can be done. Although at this point I dont have much hope that they havent started with the binding yet, but i'll still give it a shot! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problems a few times over the years, not because I'm sloppy, but with urgent work there's always a chance of missing this and that on delivery. It just happens.

Now, most of the times the client either did not even notice, or noticed, but were kind of ok with it as long as it wasn't a critical mistake that would make the print unusable.

There was a single time that I left some images in overprint by accident (working with files from another provider), so the print was totally ruined and unusable. The client was pretty furious for a day exchanging emails and calls, but it was a long-term client which I still work with today, eventually I had to offer a good discount on our next job and things settled there.

Comment: I talked to the client and he was really nice about it. He told me that it wasnt something to be worried about that much. Although i still feel guilty about it i know that these kind of mistakes sometimes happen. Since they are on a rush and wants everything to be out by the end of this month they really dont want to do anything about it anymore. I really appreciate all the answers which really helped and made me feel a lot better, so thanks!!